# Why cant you resize array in C using malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I know that malloc allows you to resize anything you want by allocating space for it. But why does this not work for resizing arrays in C?

Comment: Why is a screwdriver not good for hammering nails?

Comment: What do you mean? Show code that you think should be working but in fact isn't.

Comment: The function `malloc` does not allow you "to resize anything". It allocates memory dynamically. The function `realloc` then allows you to resize it. But because an array was not obtained from `malloc`, you can't resize it.

Comment: Arrays are on the stack.  `malloc` manipulates memory on the heap.  (In environments where those things exist.  Sometimes.  (Usually))

Comment: @WilliamPursell Arrays not only live on the stack.

Comment: Sherief, Weather is correct. If you wish to "resize", you will have to create a new array of greater length and then copy the content from the old array to the new array. This is the same thing that a Vector or ArrayList does. When you add a new element that goes beyond the capacity, they create a new array of double the size and then copy the content of the old array prior to inserting the new element.

Comment: `realloc` is what you are actually looking for.  `realloc` is a generalization of `malloc` that can resize memory as well as allocate it.

Answer (score 1):

[malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is used to allocate memory not resizing. If you want resizing check [realloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3p.html).

Comment: realloc can actually be used for allocating memory as well